# dynamic insertion of column names from json keys function and values from json

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

i'm trying to insert values into a table where table is generated dynamically so the values should also be inserted into the table based on column names (dynamic) where they are extracted using json keys function.How can i insert into the table?

```
delimiter $$
create procedure save_insertion1(in _tid int,in _insertion varchar(2000))
begin
    declare a,_length,_id int default 0;
    declare _value varchar(2) default null;
    set _length=json_length(_insertion);
    select _length;
    set a=0;
    while(_length>a) do
        set @result=(select json_keys(_insertion));
        select @result;
        set @column=(select replace(json_extract(@result,concat('$[',a,']')),'"',''));
        select @column;
        set @value=(select replace(json_extract(_insertion,concat('$.Location')),'"',''));
        select @value;
        set @ins=('insert into form(',@column,')values(',@value,')');
        prepare stmt3 from @ins;
        execute stmt3;
    end while;
end;$$
```

> Error Code: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Answer (score 0):

set @ins=concat('insert into form(',@column,')values(',@value,')');

Comment: Need to Concat input values so that it won't give error.